# Next.js app filling up disk space in production

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a problem with the size of Next.js in production. The `.next` folder is filling up disk space really quickly, which kinda make sense, but want to know if I can optimize some configurations.

The website has many pages, and languages. 18 languages with about 20'000 pages each, so ~360'000 pages in total. A lot of them are generated with `getStaticProps`. They all have the same page structure page only the data changes (like an ecommerce with products basically).

Now the problem is that if I check the `.next` folder in production **for each page** I get a 300KB HTML file and a 250KB json file for the route `<locale>/product/[id]/[...slug]`.

The file are incrementally generated so not all pages are created at build time, but only when users requests them.

With that many pages and file, I would need ~200GB disk space to store everything.

The question is: How can I avoid filling up the disk? Some pages are way less important/popular than others, so ideally I would like to have only "popular" pages saved, while all the other can be always generated when requesting the page.

I could write a script that runs periodically and delete the unwanted pages, but doesn't seems a good idea.

Comment: _"for each page I get a 300KB HTML file and a 250KB json file"_ - Have you looked into reducing the size of each page? As an alternative to incremental SSG, you could always go with SSR + Caching.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Having kind of the same issue.